# C/C++: A (*eval(A (*function)(B),B b))(){ ... } possible?? (possibly pre-C++11)

Tags: c++, c, templates, function-pointers, partial-application

in C/C++ (possibly pre-C++11), is it possible to do

```
A (*eval(A (*function)(B), B b))(){ 
  // ... ??
}
```

i.e., a function taking

1. a function returning an A value from a B value,
2. a B value to be fed to that function,

which returns
 - a function returning an A from ()
...??

If yes, would it be

- efficient??
- guaranteed the compiler generates code
  which is not executed before call of the returned function??

Thanks in advance & cheers, Nick

2014-4-20 (1): Thanks for mentioning the 'evtl.'(fixed) std::bind. :-)

So – to understand – (in C/pre C++11 without Boost) function pointers are exceptional in the way that, **inside functions**, it is **only** possible to **declare** them, but there is **no way** to **produce or modify an instance** – as function/method definitions are the **only possible sources** for function pointer instances, from where these may be handed over either explicitly, or by function/method arguments??

Just asking, as I am not clear about a possible internal representation of function pointers...

2014-4-20 (2): With the contribution of Danvil, it's time for the purpose to reveal, here the same with templates:

```
template<typename T,typename A>
struct Evaluator {
  T(*f)(A);
  A a;
  T operator()() const { return f(a); }
};

template<typename T,typename A>
Evaluator<T,A> eval(T(*f)(A), A a) {
  Evaluator<T,A> w;
  w.f= f; w.a= a;
  return w;
}
```

This works, while – as some already might guess – the whole, from arbitrary matching function/arguments collections, is intended to be sent as a zero parameter procedure into a single function/method handling execution similar to a try/catch.

For not having to use mostly identical code for each different parameter count, the actual idea was to generate the still not executed job as a such zero parameter procedure of same type for all cases.

Still, I do not find a way how to construct or modify a function pointer inside a function; 'typecasting' in some way to Evaluator does not seem practicable, does it??

Again, thanks a lot, and Happy Easter... :-)

Comment: C/C++ doesn't exist. (And what does "evtl." mean?)

Comment: @AlanStokes evtl. means eventuell.

Comment: ("Evtl." is short for the German word "eventuell", which in this context means "possibly" or "optionally".)

Comment: C++03 - `boost::bind` (but it doesn't return function pointers, but functors). Without functors it's not possible to it robustly (evtl. you can use global variables - but that's not a proper solution)

Comment: Ooops, Martin R got it - I am interfacing to a library, which (in the short run) might not support C++11, while Boost might be a real option,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for `std::bind`.  The name `std::bind` is new, previously it was part of Boost.

```
#include <functional>

std::function<A (void)> curry(A (*fn)(B), B b)
{
    return std::bind(fn, b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot – this looks like a working example. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without C++11 it could work like this:

```
typedef A(*Func)(B);

struct Evaluator {
    Func f;
    B b;
    A operator()() const
    { return f(b); }
};

Evaluator eval(Func f, B b) {
    Evaluator w;
    w.f = f;
    w.b = b;
    return w;
}
```

That's essentially what `std::bind` is doing, so use `std::bind` if you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot – a step ahead... It let me to an extension the question... :-)